# how to store json values in a variable in android studio?

Tags: android

```
{
  "server_response": [
    {
      "Pump": "Sajha",
      "Available": "1"
    },
    {
      "Pump": "Bhadrakali",
      "Available": "0"
    },
    {
      "Pump": "Kumaripati",
      "Available": "0"
    },
    {
      "Pump": "Balkhu",
      "Available": "1"
    }
  ]
}
```

I have the above json format, and i want to store these in variables to use them later for other purposes.

Comment: Parse the `Json Array` and Store each `Json Object` value in `String` variable.

Comment: store it in string

Answer (score 0):

As a temporary object you can use Json Object:

```
JSONObject my_json_holder = new JSONObject(your string name);
```

As a temporary String simply assign it to a string. However you have to replace all your doublequote (") with (\")

```
String temp= "your json here"
```

Obviously  for a long time, you have to store your string in a database.

Comment: im using wamp server, and i have created a table there as shown above, i want to retrieve those data from the server in the android studio and store it in a variable.

Comment: What you want to do with that variable? why don't you parse the json in place and not use it immediately?

Comment: i am trying to create an app, such that if the available is 1, i display a certain text, if it is 0 i display a different text

Comment: Ok. So you have to parse the received array as soon as you receive it and there is no need to save it for long time in a database or etc. I suggest Json Object to analyze it as  I mentioned in answer.

Comment: Yes please ask a new question and send me the link. I can not post codes in comments.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37452165/json-parsing-and-storing-them-in-variables

Answer (score 0):

```
String json = "{\"server_response\":[{\"Pump\":\"Sajha\",\"Available\":\"1\"},{\"Pump\":\"Bhadrakali\",\"Available\":\"0\"},{\"Pump\":\"Kumaripati\",\"Available\":\"0\"},{\"Pump\":\"Balkhu\",\"Available\":\"1\"}]}";
    try {
        JSONObject jsonObj = new JSONObject(json);
        JSONArray jsonAry = jsonObj.getJSONArray("server_response");
        for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonAry.length() ; i ++){
            JSONObject obj = jsonAry.getJSONObject(i);
            String pump = obj.getString("Pump");
            String availbale = obj.getString("Available");
        }
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Create two classes as below

```
public class ResponseBlahBlah
{
    @SerializedName("server_response")
    public PumpBlahBlahClass[] pumpObject;
}
```

and

```
public class PumpBlahBlahClass
{
@SerializedName("Pump")
public String pump;

@SerializedName("Available")
public String available;

public String getPump()
{
    return pump;
}

public void setPump(String pump)
{
    this.pump = pump;
}

public String getAvailable()
{
    return available;
}

public void setAvailable(String available)
{
    this.available = available;
}
}
```

parse as below in your code

```
ResponseBlahBlah = new Gson().fromJson(response, ResponseBlahBlah.class);
```

Comment: I forgot to tell you that you need GSON parser for the same. add it to your gradle

Answer (score 0):

You can take reference from code below to store json object in a variable:

```
               public void putJson(Context context, JSONObject jsonObject) {
                        SharedPreferences settings;
                        Editor editor;

                        settings = context.getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME,
                                Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
                        editor = settings.edit();

                        editor.putString("JSONString",        jsonObject.toString());

                        editor.commit();
                    }
```

Answer (score 0):

[Use this link for creating POJO online](http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Good thing about this link is, you only have to copy and paste the json response. 
Then you will have choice to convert it into Jackson/Gson/none

Answer (score 0):

look at this jetpack compose example

```
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.activity.ComponentActivity
import androidx.activity.compose.setContent
import androidx.compose.foundation.background
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Arrangement
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.Column
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.PaddingValues
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxHeight
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxSize
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.fillMaxWidth
import androidx.compose.foundation.layout.padding
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.LazyColumn
import androidx.compose.foundation.lazy.itemsIndexed
import androidx.compose.material3.Button
import androidx.compose.material3.MaterialTheme
import androidx.compose.material3.Text
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateListOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.mutableStateOf
import androidx.compose.runtime.snapshots.SnapshotStateList
import androidx.compose.ui.Alignment
import androidx.compose.ui.Modifier
import androidx.compose.ui.unit.dp
import com.google.gson.Gson
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import org.json.JSONArray
import org.json.JSONException
import org.json.JSONObject
import java.io.Serializable
import java.util.Date

class TestActivity : ComponentActivity() {
    val myTag = "TestActivity"

    private var messagesList: SnapshotStateList<MessageData> = mutableStateListOf()

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContent {
            Column(
                verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Top,
                horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally,
                modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize()
            ) {
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        messagesList.clear()
                        getMessages().onEach{
                            messagesList.add(it)
                        }
                        customPrint(myTag, getMessages().toList().toString())
                    },
                    content = {
                        Text("getMessages")
                    }
                )
                Button(
                    modifier = Modifier.padding(8.dp),
                    onClick = {
                        setMessages(
                            sender = "Allan",
                            message = "Hello World",
                            channel = "Channel",
                            date = Date()
                        )
                        Toast.makeText(
                            this@TestActivity,
                            "message was defined",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG
                        ).show()
                    },
                    content = {
                        Text("setMessages")
                    }
                )

                LazyColumn(
                    contentPadding = PaddingValues(top = 10.dp, start = 7.5.dp, end = 7.5.dp),
                    modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight().fillMaxWidth(),
                ) {
                    itemsIndexed(items = messagesList){ _, data ->
                        Column(
                            modifier = Modifier
                                .padding(8.dp)
                                .background(color = MaterialTheme.colorScheme.primary)
                                .fillMaxWidth()
                        ) {
                            Text(data.sender!!)
                            Text(data.message!!)
                            Text(data.channel!!)
                            Text(data.date!!.toString())
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private var messageObject = mutableStateOf(JSONObject("{ messages: [] }"))
    private val messageList = JSONArray()

    private fun setMessages(sender: String, message: String, channel: String, date: Date) {
        val messageData = JSONObject()
        try {
            messageData.put("sender", sender)
            messageData.put("message", message)
            messageData.put("channel", channel)
            messageData.put("date", date)
            messageList.put(messageData)
            messageObject.value.put("messages", messageList)

        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

    private fun getMessages(): List<MessageData> {
        val gson = Gson()
        return try {
            gson.fromJson(messageObject.value.toString(), Messages::class.java).messages
        } catch (e: JSONException) {
            e.printStackTrace()
            listOf()
        }
    }

    data class Messages(
        @SerializedName("messages")
        val messages: List<MessageData> = listOf(MessageData())
    ) : Serializable

    data class MessageData(
        @SerializedName("sender")
        val sender: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("message")
        var message: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("channel")
        var channel: String? = null,
        @SerializedName("date")
        var date: String? = null
    ) : Serializable

    private fun customPrint(myTag: String, message: String) {
        println("customLog $myTag $message")
    }
}
```