# JSON Parsing and storing them in variables

Tags: sql, json, android-studio, wamp

I am using Wamp server to create a database, and i have been able to retrieve them in android studio in JSON format, but I want to store them in variables, and the database in WAMP needs to be updated often so i want the data to be stored it a variable

> {
>     "server_response": [
>       {
>         "Pump": "Sajha",
>         "Available": "1"
>       },
>       {
>         "Pump": "Bhadrakali",
>         "Available": "0"
>       },
>       {
>         "Pump": "Kumaripati",
>         "Available": "0"
>       },
>       {
>         "Pump": "Balkhu",
>         "Available": "1"
>       }
>     ]
>   }

i.e, I want to perform a certain task when Available for a certain pump is 1 and a different task when it is 0 in android studio, how do i do it, can please someone send me the code.

Answer (score 0):

First convert the **output** json to a JSONObject and create an array through child objects. Again convert the children to Json objects and extract data:

```
String parentObject= new JSONObject(output);
String pumps= parentObject.optString("server_response").toString();
JSONArray childrenArray = new JSONArray(pumps);
for(int i=0; i < childrenArray.length(); i++)
{
   JSONObject childObject = childrenArray.getJSONObject(i);
   String Pump= childObject.optString("Pump").toString();
   String Available= childObject.optString("Available").toString();
   //if (Available.equals("1")){Do something}
}
```

You may also directly use `getString` instead of `optString` if you are sure that object is not null and so you wont need to convert it `toString()`